# Accessing sinatra variables from a proc

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

i'm using modular Sinatra, with these code

```
def is_login?
   session[:auth_token].nil? # error: undefined variable or method `session` 
end

if is_login?
   menu['Logout'] = '/logout'
else 
   menu['Login'] = '/login'
end

get '/logout' do
   session[:auth_token] = nil
end
```

those code returns an error `undefined local variable or method 'session' for main:Object`, because session only works in inside of `get`, how to make session hash accessible from outside?

i've tried another alternative, that is moving `is_login?` into helper and as a `define_method` so it could access `session`, but the similar problem arise, that i could not call `is_login?` as it's not defined, here's the code:

```
helpers do
  define_method :logged_in? do
    session[:access_token].nil?
  end
  if is_login? # error: undefined method `logged_in?`
    menus['Logout'] = '/logout'
  else
    menus['Login'] = '/login'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session only makes sense within the context of a request. Thus, using it outside (such as in the if expressions you gave above) will not succeed.

Instead, use it within a request. For example

```
get '/' do
  if is_login?
    # your code
  else
    # your code
  end
end
```